# ADO.NET: Data not being displayed properly in repeater

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am facing a peculiar issue in my ADO.NET code. This is the table data that I am accessing from a repeater from the frontend.

```
1   get car cleaned             2012-02-14 08:32:25.643         NULL
2   submit tax documents        2012-02-14 08:33:04.610         NULL
3   photo copy all documents    2012-02-14 08:33:04.610         NULL
```

Data in the first row is not being displayed at all.

If I delete the rows 2 and 3, no data is being displayed in the repeater. I think the issue is with my ADO.NET code. Also, if I truncate the table completely, the page is loading forever as opposed to displaying the "No Data Found" message in the label.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtNewTask.Focus();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetTaskList();
    }
}

protected void GetTaskList()
{

    conn = new SqlConnection(cstr);
    getTasksCmd = new SqlCommand("select Name, CreationDate, CompletionDate from tasks", conn);

    try
    {
        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (reader = getTasksCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (!reader.Read())
                {
                    lblDbMsg.Text = "No Data Found!";
                }

                rptTaskList.DataSource = reader;
                rptTaskList.DataBind();

            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the `while` loop from your code:

```
        using (reader = getTasksCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            rptTaskList.DataSource = reader;
            rptTaskList.DataBind();
        }
```

Because you are calling `SqlDataReader.Read()` once, you are moving past the first record.  Therefore, if you want to be able to retrieve all of the rows of data including the first, don't call `Read()` at all.

[SqlDataReader.Read() Method MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx)